# How to configure Resilience4j to record only specific exceptions using properties?

Tags: java, feign, resilience4j

I'm using Resilience4j to manage resilience patterns in my Java application, and I want to configure it to record only a specific type of exception while ignoring others. Specifically, I'd like to record instances of feign.RetryableException and exclude all other exceptions from being recorded by Resilience4j.

I'm aware that Resilience4j has various configuration options using properties, but I couldn't find a direct way to achieve this type of exception filtering. Is there a way to configure Resilience4j to achieve this behavior using properties, or do I need to implement a custom solution for this?

If direct configuration using properties isn't available, I'd appreciate any suggestions or examples on how to implement a custom wrapper or utility around Resilience4j to achieve the desired exception filtering behavior.

Thank you for your help!

Below config I tried which is not working for me, this also records other exceptions

resilience4j.circuitbreaker.instances.FEIGN_Client_method.record-exceptions[0]=feign.RetryableException

[Documentation for method recordExceptions(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsNOX.png)

Comment: Check answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75936688/1800319, you can add a ignoreExceptionPredicate which returns true for all the exceptions you want to ignore and false for `RetryableException`.